# Variants with Styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am building a custom tooltip component and wanted a style for it to be on the top, right, bottom or left of the DOM element. For styling, I am using styled-components. I do not know the best way to set variants of the same element. For now, I have a main style `Tooltip` and four other component that style the main style (namely, `TooltipTop`, `TooltipRight`, `TooltipBottom`, `TooltipLeft`). I have tried this:

```
const variants = {
  top: Styled.TooltipTop,
  right: Styled.TooltipRight,
  bottom: Styled.TooltipBottom,
  left: Styled.TooltipLeft,
};

let TooltipComponent = variants[
   props.direction as keyof typeof props.direction
]
? props.direction
: Styled.TooltipTop;
```

But then when using the component on the render function it throws:

> JSX element type 'TooltipComponent' does not have any construct or
> call signatures.

Do you have any tips on how I can fix this problem or a more elegant way to have variants of styled-components? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I suppose, you should use `variants[props.direction]` instead of `props.direction` to fix this error.

```
let TooltipComponent = variants[
   props.direction as keyof typeof props.direction
]
? variants[props.direction] 
: Styled.TooltipTop;
```

2. You can pass the direction as a property to a style component instead of making 4 separate components. [Read more about props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props)

```
const Tooltip = styled.div`
  /* Adapt the direction based on  prop */
  left: ${props => props.direction === 'something' ? "100px" : "0px"};
  right: ${props => props.direction === 'something' ? "0px" : "100px"};
`;

render(
  <div>
    <Tooltip direction="something">Normal</Button>
  </div>
);
```